# ews streaming connection reconnect with oAuth2

Tags: vb.net, oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices

I'm in the process of re-writing my back end service that monitors a mailbox using EWS streaming connection, I'm changing it from basic auth to oAuth2.

Everything works fine, on service start I subscribe to the mailbox, it creates an exchange service, retrieves an authentication token and then monitors the mailbox for 30 min until the streaming connection expires. I have an event handler attached to the OnDisconnect event of the subscription to re-connect automatically. Which works as well. However, the lifetime of the oAuth2 token is 1 hour. so the second time the streaming connection tries to reconnect it fails with unauthorized error code.

How do I force it to renew the oAuth token and use the renewed token fro the reconnect every 30 min when the streaming connection times out ?

Here is my code:

Get the Auth Token:

```
    Public Async Function getTokenAsync() As Task(Of String)

    Try
        Dim authority As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AuthorizationUri").Replace("common", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        Dim authenticationContext As Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext = New Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(authority, False)
        Dim certfile As String = "D:\DevRepos\Test apps\oAuth2 EWS test app\testCert.pfx"
        Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(certfile, "xxxx", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
        Dim cac As Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate = New Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate("xxxxxxxxxxxx", cert)
        Dim authenticationResult = Await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://outlook.office365.com", cac)

        Return authenticationResult.AccessToken

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try


    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Create Exchange service:

```
    Public Async Function exchangeServiceconnection() As Task(Of ExchangeService)
    Dim test As Task(Of String)
    test = getTokenAsync()
    Dim result2 As String = Await test
    Dim ewsClient = New ExchangeService()

    Try
        ewsClient.Url = New Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
        ewsClient.Credentials = New OAuthCredentials(result2)
        ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId = New ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "mailbox@testdomain.com")
        ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "mailbox@testdomain.com")

    Catch ex As MsalException
        MsgBox($"Error acquiring access token: {ex.ToString()}")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox($"Error: {ex.ToString()}")
    End Try

    Return ewsClient

End Function
```

subscribe to mailbox:

```
    Async Sub Subscribe()
    Dim service As ExchangeService
    service = Await exchangeServiceconnection()
    Dim locateMailbox = New Mailbox With {
        .Address = "mailbox@testdomain.com"
    }
    Dim folderId = New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, locateMailbox)
    Dim foldersToWatch = {folderId}
    Dim streamingSubscription As StreamingSubscription = service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(foldersToWatch, EventType.NewMail)
    Dim streamingConnection = New StreamingSubscriptionConnection(service, 30)
    streamingConnection.AddSubscription(streamingSubscription)
    AddHandler streamingConnection.OnSubscriptionError, AddressOf ResolveError
    AddHandler streamingConnection.OnDisconnect, AddressOf Reconnect
    AddHandler streamingConnection.OnNotificationEvent, AddressOf Form1.message
    streamingConnection.Open()
End Sub
```

Reconnect handler:

```
    Public Sub Reconnect(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal disconnectEventArgs As SubscriptionErrorEventArgs)
    If Not CType(sender, StreamingSubscriptionConnection).IsOpen Then
        CType(sender, StreamingSubscriptionConnection).Open()
    End If
End Sub
```

reconnect on error:

```
    Public Sub ResolveError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal errorEventArgs As SubscriptionErrorEventArgs)
    Dim streamingSubscriptionConnection = CType(sender, StreamingSubscriptionConnection)
    If Not streamingSubscriptionConnection.IsOpen Then streamingSubscriptionConnection.Open()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get away with handling the HTTP 401 and going back to OAuth to get a new token.

Comment: thanks pjneary, I've done the same and it seems to be stable now and renewing the token every 30 min. would you mind sharing your code ? I've posed mine below and it works, but not sure if this is the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

so I did the following in my reconnect function, made the exchange service public, request a new auth token on reconnect and update the service credentials with the new token.

seems to work fine now, service has been running all night no issues.

```
    Public Async Sub Reconnect(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal disconnectEventArgs As SubscriptionErrorEventArgs)
    If Not CType(sender, StreamingSubscriptionConnection).IsOpen Then
        Dim test As Task(Of String)
        test = getTokenAsync()
        result2 = Await test
        service.Credentials = New OAuthCredentials(result2)
        CType(sender, StreamingSubscriptionConnection).Open()
    End If
End Sub
```

This fixed my issue, please comment if there is a better way

Comment: so this works for about a day and then fails, if I look at the log it at some point it does not refresh the token and then fails to re-open the connection. before that however I can see it refreshing the token every hour. how can I force it to refresh the token ?